# Create SSH key so server A can access server B

Tags: ssh

I know this is a simple process, but it always confuses me.

I need to upload video from my App (server A) and send it to an encoding server (server B) via SFTP. I'm using Laravel and Ubuntu on Forge, and can only use SSH keys; SFTP usernames and passwords are not allowed.

I know how to create the key (`ssh-keygen -t rsa`), I just can't remember on which server to generate the key and on which server to add it.

Since I want to access server B from server A, do I generate a new key on server B and add it on server A?

Once the key has been created, how do I get it on the other server? Every example I come across always says to copy the key and paste into a control panel, and that's not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SSH you generate the keys on (A), keep the public key on the server you want to access(B in your case) and private will remain on the server(A) from where you want to copy. Hope, this helps.